# In Swift 3.0, how to check what button was pressed

Tags: ios, swift3, uibutton, sender

I understand that the following will return the title of a button that was pressed.

```
let myString = sender.title(for: .normal)!
```

But I would really like to understand why this works. I could not find it in Apple [documentation for UIButton](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton).

I read in another thread that `sender` is a parameter of type `Any` rather than UIButton, but I would appreciate any help in deciphering this syntax.

Comment: Usually this method is called by the system and the instance of the button is passed as a parameter. That's why in the method, you can get the button.

Answer (score 4):

You can see the type of `sender` in the method name. The code you posted will only work if sender is a `UIButton`, like in the following:

```
@IBAction func sampleMethod(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let myString = sender.title(for: .normal)
}
```

If `sender` is of type `Any`, then you must unwrap it as a `UIButton` in order to access the title the same way, like so:

```
@IBAction func sampleMethod(_ sender: Any) {
    if let sender = sender as? UIButton {
        let myString = sender.title(for: .normal)
    }
}
```

If you don't do this, the app won't compile. Type `Any` doesn't have a `title` property.

If you are creating an `IBAction` function by dragging from a storyboard to code, the default is to have the sender type be `Any`, as you can see here:

[image]

You can set it to `UIButton` by using the drop down menu next to Type, like so:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The **Target-Action** mechanism is described in the documentation for the [`UIControl`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol) class, which is class that actionable controls, such as `UIButton`, inherit from.

Essentially, the action function must implement one of the following signatures:

- `doSomething()`
- `doSomething(_ sender: Any)`
- `doSomething(_ sender: Any, event: UIEvent)`

The `sender` parameter will be the control that sent the action.

`Any` in Swift is a special type that can represent any type but it is not an actual type, so if the sender is a `UIButton` then `sender` will be an instance of `UIButton`, but you can't access any of it's specific methods or properties unless you downcast it.  You could say something like:

```
func doSomething(_ sender: Any) {
    if let button = sender as? UIButton {
          let myString = button(for: .normal)
}
```

However, generally you know how you have connected your controls and action handlers, so there is no need to conditionally downcast; you can use an explicit downcast:

```
func doSomething(_ sender: Any) {
    let button = sender as! UIButton 
    let myString = button(for: .normal)
}
```

Or, even more succinctly:

```
func doSomething(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let myString = button(for: .normal)
}
```

Now, if you mistakenly connected `doSomething` to an action on a text field, these last two forms would give you a runtime crash as the downcast fails; but hopefully you catch this during testing and so it is generally considered "safe" to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
 guard let string = ((sender) as AnyObject).title(for: .normal)
    else{
        return
    }
    print(string)
```

This will also work.(If you don't know the type of sender)

But most common way for button is

```
let string = (sender as! UIButton).title(for: .normal)
print(str!)
```

Comment: The compiler's not going to let you call `title(for:)` on an `AnyOnject`.